# Printing a string containing Arabic characters results in question marks. How to fix?

Tags: java, encoding, arabic

When I print a string containing Arabic characters in Java, it's displayed as `??????`. How can I fix this?

The arabic string result from the [BiDi algorithm implementation](http://www.unicode.org/Public/PROGRAMS/BidiReferenceJava/BidiReferenceTest.java.txt) it's supposed to support Arabic as `RTL` language

Comment: What OS? Do you have a Unicode font available which supports Arabic script? Does Java know about the font?

Comment: Could you tell us more about that Arabic String? Where you get in from: is it hardcoded in some class, from user input, database, external file? Also what is encoding of your Java file and how you execute it?

Comment: any solution sir did you find on this ? @adham

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
Character.codepointAt(arabicString, 0)
```

to check that the String actually contains Unicode codepoints from the Arabic set?

Alternatively you could use

```
Character.UnicodeBlock block =
        Character.UnicodeBlock.of(Character.codepointAt(arabicString, 0));
```

and then check that `block` has a value equal to `Character.UnicodeBlock.ARABIC`.

If the String does contain Arabic codepoints then the problem is likely with your output console. Possibly you have no fonts that can display characters for those codepoints.

If the String does not contain Arabic codepoints then you're getting unexpected results from the provider of the String.